# Data Management / Vector Manipulations (In the R language)

Tags: r, statistics

The general algorithm I need to implement in R is:

```
z_i=min(x_i-y_i-a,x_i-b).
```

I am using i as an index for my z,y, and x vectors.  Z is the new vector that I would like to use in my regression model.  If have tried with no success using various types of loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want the `pmin` function.

```
set.seed(21)
x <- runif(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
a <- 1
b <- 0.5
pmin(x-y-a,x-b)
# [1] -0.64701585 -0.24755440  0.19925230 -0.87903259 -0.03799284
# [6]  0.41868340 -1.65560767 -0.32780832 -0.18654580 -0.71345697
```

Comment: That will give me a general z_i, i=[1,...,1000], so I need something more elegant than that.

Comment: @Jerome: I don't know what "a general z_i" is.  It would really help if you could provide an example.

Comment: A general z_i is just the "i"th component of the z vector.  I have two vectors (x,y) in this case and I am transforming them index by index according the the aforementioned algorithm.  I need a way to take the pmin function (shown above) and loop that 1000 or so times.  I did not mention that function in my original post because I was not sure that was the most robust solution to this problem.

Comment: Many R functions are vectorized, meaning they already work element-by-element.  `pmin` is one such function.  You don't need to muck about with defining `z_i`, `x_i`, `y_i`, etc.  The output of `pmin` will be the same length as your `x` and `y` vectors.  You don't need a loop.

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure how I missed that.